# spring mongo querydsl Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl, spring-mongodb

I use spring mongo data rest and querydsl

the domain: has a property:

```
 @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)

  private LocalDateTime registerTime;
```

To use Json ,I add :

> jackson-datatype-jsr310

the LocalDateTime can work :

> "http://localhost:8001/api/users"
>
> it displays: '2016-10-26T21:08:58.91'

when i use querydsl with controller :

```
 @GetMapping("/admin/queryWithPage")
        public Page<User> get(
                @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10, sort = "id", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,

                @RequestParam(value = "registerTimeBegin", required = false)
                @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime registerTimeBegin,
                @RequestParam(value = "registerTimeEnd", required = false)
                @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime registerTimeEnd,

        ){
        QUser user=new QUser("user");
        Predicate registerTimePredicate=null;

        boolean registerTimeNotNull=registerTimeBegin!=null&&registerTimeEnd!=null;

         if(registerTimeNotNull){
                    registerTimePredicate=user.registerTime.
                            between(registerTimeBegin,registerTimeEnd);
                }

       return  repository.findAll(registerTimePredicate,pageable);

    }
```

it has err:

```
2016-10-28 12:23:45.678 ERROR 21101 --- [io-8001-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime.] with root cause

org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:210) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:61) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.writeValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:133) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:112) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:40) ~[bson-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.sendMessage(CommandProtocol.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:111) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:215) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation$1.call(CountOperation.java:210) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation$1.call(CountOperation.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:53) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:962) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:937) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:931) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:914) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:885) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.count(DBCollection.java:824) ~[mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.mongodb.AbstractMongodbQuery.fetchCount(AbstractMongodbQuery.java:391) ~[querydsl-mongodb-4.1.4.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.mongodb.AbstractMongodbQuery.fetchResults(AbstractMongodbQuery.java:376) ~[querydsl-mongodb-4.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.findAll(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:144) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.xdidian.keryhu.user_account.rest.admin.AdminRest.get(AdminRest.java:173) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.BUILD-20161026.111618-53.jar:1.4.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.BUILD-20161026.111618-53.jar:1.4.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.BUILD-20161026.111618-53.jar:1.4.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.BUILD-20161027.083248-22.jar:4.3.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

**update**:

If I change

> user.registerTime.between(registerTimeBegin,registerTimeEnd)

to

> user.registerTime.after(registerTimeBegin)
>                       .and(user.registerTime.before(registerTimeEnd));

the err is missing .....

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to use a `LocalDate` instance (instead of `Date`: this is the first result that shows up):

```
Date dateValue = Date.from(Instant.from(localDateValue.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("GMT"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `registerTimeBegin`, `registerTimeEnd`  (LocalDateTime) object to `Date` Object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTimeBegin = registerTimeBegin.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
Date registerTimeBeginDate = Date.from(zdtTimeBegin.toInstant());

ZonedDateTime zdtTimeEnd = registerTimeEnd.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
Date registerTimeEndDate = Date.from(zdtTimeEnd .toInstant());
```

And do

```
user.registerTime(registerTimeBeginDate ,registerTimeEndDate );
```

This works